# Why can you not use Gauss law to calculate the electric field a distance $D$ away from a charged cube?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law, coulombs-law

Why can one not use Gauss law to calculate the electric field a distance $D$ away from a charged cube? I have read that the electric field at the face of the cube is not perpendicular or parallel to the surface. Why is it not perpendicular to the surface as in the case when you have a charged sphere?

And if you are not supposed to use Gauss law, how would one then find an expression for the electric field a distance $D$ away from a charged cube?

Comment: How would you relate $\mathbf E$ to $\int\mathbf E\cdot d\mathbf A$ for any closed surface around a cube? (Do you understand how you *can* relate them for a charged *sphere*?)

Comment: Yes I understand how you would relate them to a charged sphere, because in that case the electric field is in radial direction. But I don't see why there would be a relationship for a sphere but not for a cube, why is it not perpendicular?

Comment: Draw your proposed field, everywhere perpendicular to the nearest face. Does it look sensible, especially far from the cube, where the cube appears to be a point charge? And what happens at edges and corners in your field?

Comment: Thank you for the help! If I may ask, I have only encountered Gauss law for spheres and cylinders, are these the ones that are "easy" to integrate over and have symmetry? Or are there any other shapes that are usual and one should know as well?

Comment: Infinite planes.

Comment: Note: Asking about “a charged cube” is vague and ambiguous. You probably mean a nonconducting cube with uniform volume charge density $\rho$. But another possibility is a conducting cube with charge on its surface; the surface charge density $\sigma$ will be nonuniform because the charges are free to move and will repel each other so that there is higher charge density at the corners.

Comment: okey, thank you, why is the surface charge density nonuniform for a conducting cube?

Comment: My last sentence explained that. (I think it’s right but I’m not 100% sure that it is max at the corners.)

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that by 'Gauss' Law,' you mean the integral form
$$\int_{\partial \Omega} \mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{S} = \frac{Q}{\varepsilon_0} = \int_\Omega \frac{\rho(\mathbf{x})}{\epsilon_0} dV$$
(which is equivalent to the differential form $\nabla\cdot \mathbf{E} = \frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\rho(\mathbf{x})$ ).

In the classic argument for electric field outside of a charged sphere using the integral form, most of the physics comes from symmetry: the charge distribution is symmetric under the action of rotations, and so it follows that the generated field must exhibit the same symmetry. Any deviation of $\mathbf{E}$ from the radial direction would break this rotational symmetry, so it is not allowed - this allows one to simplify $\mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{S} = E_r dS$

A cube, on the other hand, does not exhibit this structure. Its electric field will be direction dependent, meaning that one must instead solve the PDE given above. The other issue is what the cube is made of: if it is indeed a *uniformly* charged cube, it is presumably an insulator, and the electric field at the surface is not necessarily normal to the surface. (If it were conducting, that would be a different situation - charges could rearrange themselves within the cube).

To see this, imagine abstracting the cube to one large positive sphere in the centre, and 8 smaller 'edge spheres' at the vertices. The electric field will only be normal where symmetry allows - at vertices and edges.

P.S. Just the distance $D$ is not enough information to tell you the electric field outside the cube (unless it is far enough away that it looks like a sphere). You also need the orientation: are you facing a flat part of a vertex?

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, I understand now. In the case where the cube is conducting, should I image it as being made up of small spheres? And can one apply Gauss law in that case?

Comment: The uniformly charged cube should be thought of as being made of a large number of small spheres, a conducting cube is a beast best understood via the scalar potential. The charges rearrange themselves in space to maintain constant potential at the surface.

Comment: Thank you for the help!